# android call answer / reject application

Tags: android, call

There are correct solution for task?

On incoming call hide defalut answer/reject activity and show my activity with two buttons "Answer" (answer on call) and "Reject" (reject call)

on 2.3.3 I9001 i use

1. Service with TelephonyManager.listen for intercept call
2. Show my activity (with 1 second delay) with flags FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK  Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT
3. On answer i use emulate KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK
4. On regect i use ITelephony hack

But this not work on 4.0.4.

a) my activity showed but hide by default

b) may be there are correct way for all version

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
Class c = Class.forName(tm.getClass().getName());
Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
m.setAccessible(true);
ITelephony telephonyService;
telephonyService = (ITelephony)m.invoke(tm);
telephonyService.silenceRinger();
telephonyService.answerRingingCall();
```

Comment: u dont need to hide default one,Open urs